# Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /home/deus/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Tags: go-ethereum

I am getting this error. Geth is already running.
Please help.

Comment: Is that the correct data directory (i.e. `/home/deus/.ethereum`) for the instance of Geth you have running, or did you specify a different location when you started Geth? (Might help if you edit your question to include the command you used to start Geth with, as well as the command you're trying to use for the attach.)

Comment: Thanks @RichardHorrocks, I missed the period. It's up and running now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it working :-)